# PHP file_get_contents with multiple urls

Tags: php, url, file-get-contents

So basically what I'm trying to do is for each row that has been generated by the query, I try to generate a URL and visit that URL. The funny part is that it always only visits the FIRST generated URL and never visits the others.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me.

```
$query = "SELECT distinct b.productname, b.seller, b.price, b.offerid 
          from tracker b";
$results = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);

$rows = array();
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $rows[] = $row;

    foreach ($rows as $row) { 
        $url = 'url'.$i;
        $$url = 'https://bla.com/tools/tracker.php?productID=' .
                $row["productname"] . '&verkoper=' . 
                $row["seller"] . '&offerid=' . 
                $row["offerid"] . '&price=' . $row["price"] . 
                '&productTracken=';

        // set URL and other appropriate options
        file_get_contents($$url);

        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you simplify what you are doing you may get the result you want

All you seem to be doing is touching a list of urls built from data in a table

Also you dont need a while loop and a foreach loop, that is what is definitely causing your problems.

```
$query = "SELECT distinct b.productname, b.seller, b.price, b.offerid 
          from tracker b";
$results = $dbcon->query($query);

while ($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

    $url = 'https://bla.com/tools/tracker.php?productID=' .
                $row["productname"] . '&verkoper=' . 
                $row["seller"] . '&offerid=' . 
                $row["offerid"] . '&price=' . $row["price"] . 
                '&productTracken=';

    // set URL and other appropriate options
    file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Comment: [`file_get_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) can use URL if the `fopen` wrappers have been enabled. Maybe use cURL as alternative is recommended?

Comment: I got this from the logs site usage logs. It only visits the first URL in the array for some reason..

[17/Nov/2021:17:33:02 +0100] "GET /tools/tracker.php?productID=112&verkoper=b12&offerid=123&price=6&productTracken= HTTP/1.0" 302 30202 "-" "-"

Comment: Using this code? Or your original code. ___Small Point___ You dont have an array, I dont have an array, this code gets one row at a time from a resultset and makes it into a url

Comment: [HTTP Eror 302 explained](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302)

Comment: Using your code. 302 doesnt really matter as I see that the URL has been visited, just not the other URL's..

Comment: Please check the results from that query using something like `phpMyAdmin`. Is there actually more than one row on your database?

Comment: And have you checked the PHP Error logs for any clues

Comment: Yes, there are 4 rows from that query. There are no errors.

Comment: Then there is no explanation for not doing 4 `file_get_contents()` Try adding an echo in there so you can see hwo many times round the loop it goes

Comment: It returns 4 URL's as expected. I only see 1 GET on the first URL tho.

Comment: So suddenly this line `// set URL and other appropriate options` has become a little ominious, so what else is going on in there

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of odd things happening here.

First, your loops:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $rows[] = $row;

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
```

Each time you fetch a row from the database, you add it to an array. You then immediately loop over *all the items in that array*. If you output a row number each time, you'd get 0; then 0, 1; then 0, 1, 2; and so on.

Secondly, your URL variable:

```
$url = 'url'.$i;
$$url = 'https://...';
```

This uses an esoteric feature of PHP called [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php): you choose dynamically what variable name you want. This feature is basically *never* needed, because it's almost always better to use an array:

```
$urls[$i] = 'https://...';
```

In this case, though, you're only using one value at a time, so you can just use a plain old variable:

```
$url = 'https://...';
```

Fixing these gives you the code in [RiggsFolly's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70007969/157957), and will probably fix your problem.